# jQuery DOM Building Indentation

Tags: jquery, formatting, indentation

It's my 2nd day learning jQuery and I love it so far (It reminds me of LISP) but I've got a question about a way to format something (or possibly use a function I'm unaware of).
I have an array of objects called myDocuments and I'm currently building a table using the following code:

```
jQ('<table/>').addClass('grid').attr('id', 'myDocumentTable')
    .append(jQ('<thead/>')
        .append(createHeaderRow(['Title', 'File', 'Updated By', 'Updated On'])))
    .append(jQ('<tbody/>')
        .append(jQ.map(myDocuments, function(myDocument){
            return jQ('<tr/>')
                .on({
                    mouseover: function(){jQ(this).addClass('rowHighlight');},
                    mouseout: function(){jQ(this).removeClass('rowHighlight');}
                .append(jQ('<td/>').text(myDocument.title))
                .append(jQ('<td/>')
                    .append(jQ('<a/>').addClass('file-download').attr('href', "fileOpener?id="+myDocument.fileId).text(myDocument.fileName)))
                .append(jQ('<td/>').text(myDocument.userName))
                .append(jQ('<td/>').text(myDocument.updatedOn))
                [0];
    })))
```

I really ike the fact that if you look at the indentation it mimics the HTML perfectly which makes it very easy to read.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Now let's say that I want to build a structure like the following

```
<div id='myDocumentDiv'
    <h3>docTitle1</h3>
    <div>docInfo1</div>
    <h3>docTitle2</h3>
    <div>docInfo2</div>
    <h3>docTitle3</h3>
    <div>docInfo3</div>
</div>
```

Each one of myDocuments will now create an `<h3>` and a `<div>` (instead of just a singe element `<tr>`). I can not figure out a good way to write the code so that it matches the HTML indentation without making the javascript harder to read.

Originally I came across this problem because I wanted to see how a jQuery.ui accordion would look. I realize that I could wrap the `<h3>` and `<div>` in an outer `<div>` and use the accordion's `:header` attribute but I am curious as to what answers people come up with anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The example could be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yangchenyun/JCr9T/).

you could use jquery's `html` to create a bundle of html elements at once. To preserve the indentation, use string operator `+` for each line of the html code.

```
$('<div id="myDocumentDiv"' +
        '<h3>docTitle1</h3>' +
        '<div>docInfo1</div>' +
        '<h3>docTitle2</h3>' +
        '<div>docInfo2</div>' +
        '<h3>docTitle3</h3>' +
        '<div>docInfo3</div>' +
    '</div>')
.appendTo('#container');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var $element = $( '<div/>' );
for( var x = 0; x < 3; x++ ){

    var $header = $( '<h3/>' );
    $header.html( 'My header ' + x );

    var $body = $( '<div/>' );
    $body.html( 'My Body ' + x );

    $element.append( $header );
    $element.append( $body );

}
```

I use the $ in the variable name to indicate that it's not a DOM element, but a DOM element wrapped in a query object.

So if I were to get the raw element:

```
var dom_element = $element[0];
```

I wouldn't use the $ prefix.

Hope that helps...